# What is the least time-consuming way to solve a system of nonlinear equations?

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-functions, economics

I am developing an equilibrium model where producers weight benefits and costs to choose the optimal time they work. However, the relevant benefit and cost functions are both rational, which results in a complex first-order derivative of the problem. When parameter values are introduced, I get systems of 3 equations in 3 variables just like the following:

eq1 = (10940*((12034*x)/35 + (1094*y)/5 + (2734*z)/25))/(7*(((12034*x)/35 + (1094*y)/5 + (2734*z)/25)^2 + 640000)) - (10940*((12034*x)/35 + (1094*y)/5 + (2734*z)/25)^3)/(7*(((12034*x)/35 + (1094*y)/5 + (2734*z)/25)^2 + 640000)^2) == x^3/5184

eq2 = (10940*((1094*x)/15 + (51418*y)/105 + (2734*z)/25))/(7*(((1094*x)/15 + (51418*y)/105 + (2734*z)/25)^2 + 640000)) - (10940*((1094*x)/15 + (51418*y)/105 + (2734*z)/25)^3)/(7*(((1094*x)/15 + (51418*y)/105 + (2734*z)/25)^2 + 640000)^2) == y^2/576

eq3 = (5468*((1094*x)/15 + (1094*y)/5 + (30074*z)/75))/(5*(((1094*x)/15 + (1094*y)/5 + (30074*z)/75)^2 + 490000)) - (5468*((1094*x)/15 + (1094*y)/5 + (30074*z)/75)^3)/(5*(((1094*x)/15 + (1094*y)/5 + (30074*z)/75)^2 + 490000)^2) == z^2/576

It has usually taken around 48 hs for MATLAB to find solutions for such systems of equations - when it does find them - using the solve command. Is there a more efficient way to complete this task? (I do have a pretty clear guess at what solutions should look like: all three outcome variables are expected to be within the [0,12] interval.)

Comment: Is a (rounded) numerical result sufficient? Mathematica for example solves your sample equation within 1 second. Can you show your MatLab code?

Comment: Please show your code. How are you solving the equations now?

Comment: Certainly yes, JimiLoe, my results need only be rounded to one decimal place.

Comment: Mathematica solves it beautifully by approximation. Thanx for that one, JimiLoe!